# NHibernate OrderBy a correlated subquery

Tags: nhibernate, correlated-subquery

I have a `parent` which has a collection of `property`. Each `property` has a `propertyclass` and a `value`. I want to return a list of `parent` ordered by the `value` of attached any attached `property` with a given `propertyclass`

Let's say the `parent` represents a car, there exists a `property` with `propertyclass` "color". I want to return a list of all cars ordered by the value of the "color" property.

In straight SQL, this would be easy, we could just order by a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM [Parent] 
ORDER BY (SELECT [Value] FROM [Property] WHERE [PropertyClass] = 'Color' 
  AND [ParentId] = [Parent].[Id])
```

But I do not know how to accomplish this at all in NHibernate.

I've gotten as far as creating a Subquery projection and setting the order-by of the query using it:

```
var dc = DetachedCriteria.For<Core.Property>()
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PropertyClass", sortByProperty))
  .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Value"));
var query = baseQuery.OrderBy(Projections.SubQuery(dc));
```

But the order-by clause generated by this misses the correlated subquery part- `[ParentId] = [Parent].[Id]`, thus is invalid sql. How do I make this subquery correlated to the base query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Core.Property propAlias = null;

baseQuery.JoinAlias(parent => parent.Properties, () => propAlias)
  .Where(() => propAlias.PropertyClass == sortByProperty);

var query = baseQuery.OrderBy(() => propAlias.Value);
```